# How to remove options from a selectize dropdown according to a selection from another selectize dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, selectize.js

I am using JavaScript Selectize dropdown. I want to change payment types as per the selection of reseravtion type in my code.
Code is as following,

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#reservationType").change(function () {           
         managePaymentTypes();
    });      
});

var $reservationTypeObj = $('#reservationType').selectize({
    sortField: {
       field: localStorage.getItem("selectizeField"),
       direction: localStorage.getItem("selectizeDirection")
    },
       dropdownParent: localStorage.getItem("selectizeDropdownParent")
});

var $paymentTypeObj = $('#paymentType').selectize({
    sortField: {
       field: localStorage.getItem("selectizeField"),
       direction: localStorage.getItem("selectizeDirection")
    },
        dropdownParent: localStorage.getItem("selectizeDropdownParent")
});

function managePaymentTypes(){
   var resType = $('#reservationType :selected').val();
      if(resType==202){
        //remove option 2 - Salary deduct in selectize.
      }else if(resType==101) {
        //remove option 1 - Credit in selectize. 
      }else{
        ////
      }
}
```

```html
<label class="col-md-1 control-label firstcol" for="type" style="text-align:left">Reservation Type : </label> 
<div class="col-md-2" id="reservationTypeDiv" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body"  data-placement="bottom">
 <select class="demo-default selectized" id="reservationType" name="reservationType" tabindex="7"  opacity: 1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-container="body"  data-placement="bottom">
  <%
  for (int l = 0; l < reservationTypes.size(); l++)
  {
  %>
   <option value="<%=reservationTypes.get(l).getId()%>"><%=reservationTypes.get(l).getDescription()%></option>
  <%
  }
  %>
 </select>    
</div>
<label class="col-md-1 control-label firstcol" for="payment" style="text-align:left">Payment Type : </label> 
<div class="col-md-2" data-toggle="tooltip" id="paymentTypeDiv" data-container="body"  data-placement="bottom">
 <select class="demo-default selectized" id="paymentType"       name="paymentType" tabindex="7" opacity: 1" data-      toggle="tooltip" data-container="body"  data-placement="bottom">
  <%
  for (int l = 0; l < reservationPaymentTypes.size(); l++)
  {
  %>
   <option value="<%=reservationPaymentTypes.get(l).getId()%>"><%=reservationPaymentTypes.get(l).getDescription()%></option>
  <%
  }
  %>
 </select>    
</div>
```

I have two selectize dropdowns.

1. For reservation type
2. For payement type

Values are getting from database. 
[Reservation types drop-down screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u813N.png),[Payment types drop-down screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt8vy.png)

When reservation type changes I want to change the payment types. 
Therefore onchange of reservation type I have called a method named managePaymentTypes(). I want to remove Credit payment option when reservation type is Individual(101). And I want to remove Salary deduct option when reservation type is Coporate(202). Individual should be default selection. This is my requirement. Someone please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I have came up with the following solution.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {      
<%
    for(SportsCenterReservationPaymentType paymentType : reservationPaymentTypes){
    %>
        paymentTypes.push({id: <%=paymentType.getId()%>, desc: '<%=paymentType.getDescription()%>'});
    <%
    }
    %>
    $("#reservationType").change(function () {           
        loadResourceTable();
        managePaymentTypes();
    });
```

});

```
function managePaymentTypes(){ 
    var resType = $('#reservationType :selected').val();
    $('#paymentType')[0].selectize.clearOptions();

    if(resType==202&& resType!=101){

        $.each(paymentTypes, function (idx, obj) {
            if(obj.id!=333){
              $('#paymentType')[0].selectize.addOption({value:obj.id,text:obj.desc})  
            }
        });
    }

    if(resType==101&&resType!=202){

        $.each(paymentTypes, function (idx, obj) {
            if(obj.id!=222){
              $('#paymentType')[0].selectize.addOption({value:obj.id,text:obj.desc})  
            }
        });
    }
```

}